# how to install rsh/rlogin on RHEL 9

Tags: rhel, rsh

I need to install rsh/rlogin services on a RHEL9 host. It looks like these services were removed from the distribution and also from EPEL.

I know all the reasons not to install these, but I need to anyway.  Is there a way I can do it?

Comment: good 'ole *rlogin* those were the days

Comment: my guess would be to first try and scavenge the contents of ``rsh` and `rsh-server-0.17-80.el7.x86_64.rpm` from RHEL/CentOS 7.  If the existing `rsh` executable works then good otherwise build from source code getting the devel part of it from that part of the RHEL/CentOS install.

Comment: https://github.com/gsliepen/rsh-redone   ?

Comment: It's available in Fedora EPEL 8